# Getting global log filter to capture key/value data from another job in Rundeck

Tags: rundeck

I use Rundeck to execute the Job A. In Job A, I have a Global Log Filter that captures key/value data using the default regex (`RUNDECK:DATA:...`).

I call another job - Job B - that prints stuff starting with RUNDECK:DATA:key = value. I execute Job B from Job A. Somehow the Global Log Filter that I setup in Job A doesn't parse the output of Job B.

I added the same Global Log Filter to Job B, and see that the data is captured correctly, but it is not available on Job A so that it can be used on the following steps.

Does anyone know if it is possible to capture key/value from the output of a another job? I managed to capture values from steps of the same job, but not when the output comes from an execution of another called job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking your last comment the easiest way to do that is to use a file that stores the value (on JobB) and later is processed by the JobA next steps. Basically the JobA launches JobB via [Job Reference Step](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#job-reference-step), then JobB generates the data on a file, and the JobA recovers that value from the temporal file on the next steps.

JobA:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>a0daf1e3-e918-43dc-b232-bc46a7a287b6</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>JobA</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "starting Job A"</exec>
      </command>
      <command>
        <description>Job B call that geneates the temp value</description>
        <jobref name='JobB' nodeStep='true'>
          <uuid>ba183d3b-67d9-4499-b863-da8b7ac8aef3</uuid>
        </jobref>
      </command>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "printing the Job B value"</exec>
      </command>
      <command>
        <exec>cat tempfile.txt</exec>
        <plugins>
          <LogFilter type='key-value-data'>
            <config>
              <invalidKeyPattern>\s|\$|\{|\}|\\</invalidKeyPattern>
              <logData>true</logData>
              <regex>^(mykey)\s*=\s*(.+)$</regex>
            </config>
          </LogFilter>
        </plugins>
      </command>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "the value is ${data.mykey}"</exec>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>a0daf1e3-e918-43dc-b232-bc46a7a287b6</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

JobB:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>ba183d3b-67d9-4499-b863-da8b7ac8aef3</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>JobB</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "Generating the value..."</exec>
      </command>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "mykey=myvalue" &gt; tempfile.txt</exec>
      </command>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "Value generated on temp file"</exec>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>ba183d3b-67d9-4499-b863-da8b7ac8aef3</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Comment: Thanks @MegaDrive68k. The thing is that the values are going to be generated by Job B, which I need to reuse on a later step at Job A. I don't have the values at Job A prior calling Job B.

Comment: I see! I changed my answer, basically JobB stores the value on a temporal file and you can use on any Job as a ${data.mydata} Hope it helps!

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot! :D